# iPhone crash report when using replaceScene with cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, crash

When I use `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:_VGameTest];`, I get the following error, but only occasionally. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried profiler to find the cause?

Comment: crash was in your UserCenterLayer.m file in onExit() method at line 1788, as I can see on this image (or 1708, image with such bad quality is not good solution for text). what are you doing at this line?

Comment: i do this:
    if (_VInfoLayer!=nil) {
        [_VInfoLayer removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
        _VInfoLayer=nil;
    }                 and _VInfoLayer is a cclayer .maybe i can delete this...but the crash  will be solved???

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt you put :

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[_VGameTest scene]];
```

in

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:_VGameTest];` ...  ??